# UITableViewCell from Xib, cell hight and cell selection area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a UITableViewController, which has a custom cell that I want to display an image and labels. screenshots can explain my problem very well, it looks like this

[image].

And when I select any cell it looks like

[image]

In tableviewcontroller cell is not visible in proper shape according to constraints 
here is my custom cell with autolayout constraints 
[image]

How I can fix this issue? ... I created this tableviewcontroller programmatically without using storyboard.
here is code sample of data source and delegates of tableviewcontroller

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var numOfSections: Int = 0
    let count = conversations.count
    if count > 0 {
        //  tableView.separatorStyle     = .none
        numOfSections                = 1
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    }
    else
    {
        let frame                   = CGRect(x: 0,
                                             y: 0,
                                             width: tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                             height: tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel    = UILabel(frame: frame)
        noDataLabel.text            = "You don't have any messages. "
        noDataLabel.textColor       = UIColor.black
        noDataLabel.textAlignment   = .center
        tableView.backgroundView    = noDataLabel
        tableView.separatorStyle    = .none
    }
    return numOfSections
}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return conversations.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inboxCell", for: indexPath) as! InboxCell

    cell.conversation = conversations[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let uids = conversations[indexPath.row].conversationUseruids
    for uid in uids{

        if uid == Account.account.user.uid{

        }
        else{

            User.getUser(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                self.selectedUser.append(user!)
            })
        }


    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let index = indexPath.row as Int
    messageVC.conversationIndex = index
    messageVC.conversation = self.conversations[index]


    navigationController?.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: true)


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 80
}
```

Comment: You can use the tableview from storyboard and make sure you have set the proper auto layout then you can use the code of dynamic height of tableview cells.

Comment: click on image clear constraint than set proper constraint like upper lower and both side and give them height and width

Comment: it happen because you image not have upper lower constraint if not working than let me know

Comment: @RealmOfFire thank you so much its working fine :) issue was constraints on Image

Comment: @ShaheryarMalik can you accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happen because your image not have upper lower constraint if not working than let me know